# inherit to admin controller, with Admin_interface, inherited_resources and Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, inherited-resources, admin-interface

I need a backend for administration, I tried **RailsAdmin** and **ActiveAdmin**, but the limited level of customization and found the gem [admin_interface](https://github.com/joost/admin_interface) which gave me the options I wanted.

This is the structure of my project

```
├── app
│   ├── assets
│   ├── controllers
│   │   ├── admin
│   │   │   ├── locations_controller.rb
│   │   ├── application_controller.rb
│   │   ├── locations_controller.rb
│   ├── models
│   │   ├── location.rb

class LocationsController < InheritedResources::Base
  respond_to :html, :json
  def index
    @locations = Location.all
    @json = Location.all.to_gmaps4rails
  end
end

class Admin::LocationsController < Admin::ResourceController  
  # See admin/resource_controller.rb for more info..
end

class Admin::ResourceController < Admin::BaseController

  inherit_resources # gem
  defaults :route_prefix => 'admin'

  # inherited_resources options
  # nested_belongs_to :user, :optional => true

  def destroy_all
    destroyed_resources = resource_class.destroy_all(:id => params[:ids])
    flash[:notice] = "#{destroyed_resources.size} objects destroyed."
    redirect_to :back
  end

protected

  # Overwrites inherited_resources gem version.
  # Use meta_search and kaminari gem to load collection
  def collection
    @search ||= end_of_association_chain.search(params[:q])
    get_collection_ivar || begin
      c = @search.result.page(params[:page]).per(params[:per])
      set_collection_ivar(c.respond_to?(:scoped) ? c.scoped : c)
    end
  end
end
```

As I can do to make **admin>application_controller.rb** inherits from **application_controller.rb.** I want **@json = Lugar.all.to_gmaps4rails** This also available for the admin controller?.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please make sure to write what problem you are facing ?

Comment: Not how to make my backend-controller inherits from the controller, I know I set the gem [inherited_resources][https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources] not know how or where?

Comment: I guess you could create a class in between like:

**class Admin::GeoController < Admin::BaseController**
  # add your stuff
**end**
Make others inherit from this class. (Thanks Joost Hietbrink)